# Hamiltonian from the equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

The equation of motion is

$$(1+e\cos f)\frac{d^2\theta}{df^2}-2e\sin f\frac{d\theta}{df}-\frac{w^2}{2}\sin 2(f-\theta)=0,$$
where $0<e<1$, $w\in const$. Taking $q=\theta$ and $p=\frac{d\theta}{df}$, with the use of the Hamilton equations

$$\frac{dq}{df}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p},\qquad \frac{dp}{df}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q},$$

how can I find the Hamiltonian $H=H(p,q,f)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on a previous answer and comment: there is no trick to solving this problem.

Start from the perfectly general Lagrangian
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}G(q,t)\dot{q}^2 +F(q,t)\dot q - V(q,t)
$$
and obtain the equation of motion
$$
G(q,t)\ddot{q}+\frac{\partial G(q,t)}{\partial t}\dot{q}+
\frac{\partial F(q,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial V(q,t)}{\partial q}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial G(q,t)}{\partial q}\dot{q}^2=0\, .
$$
You can then compare to your form to deduce $G(q,t)$, $F(q,t)$ and 
$V(q,t)$.  From this you can obtain the Hamiltonian
$$
H=p\dot{q}-L\, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Start with a Lagrangian formulation
   $$ L~:=~\frac{1}{2}(1+e\cos t)^2\dot{q}^2 -V, \qquad V~:=~-\frac{w^2}{4}(1+e\cos t) \cos 2(q-t). \tag{1} $$
2. Next Legendre transform to obtain the Hamiltonian formulation.